# unit testing with mock and possibility of unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am new in unit testing.

```
 public List<BookList> GetBookList(int bookid)
    {
        List<BookList> _BookList = new List<BookList>();
    //Consider if some wcf call is there then how we can develop unit test
        using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext(_strConnectionStringName))
        {
            foreach (tblBook_Sel_BasedOnbookIDResult _tblBook_selResult in context.tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID(bookid))
            {
                BookList _bookListObject = new BookList();
                //Setting the proerty here
                _BookList .Add(_bookListObject);
            }

        }
        return _BookList;
    }
```

I want to write unit test for this method.Please  suggest which scenario of the above function i can test through unit testing and how .I can understand better if you can elaborate with some code example and how mocking can help us in above scenario.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to start unit testing, you first might want to get your hands on some practises which improve testability. You're not using interfaces, you use hardcode dependencies. Infer-On his anwser is getting pretty close to what you should be doing. Following his example should allow you to easily mock out the database and create a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a strong dependency to data access class, so probably you should inject it, if you have context as class member,initialized by injection from constructor, you easily can mock it from your unit test; the best approach is to have a contructor with IDataAccess parameter.

EDIT:
probably there is some problem to this snippet, but the idea is:

```
public interface IDataClassesDataContext
{
  tblBook_Sel_BasedOnbookIDResult tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID(int bookid);
}

public partial class DataClassesDataContext:IDataClassesDataContext
{

}

public class Class1
{
  IDataClassesDataContext _context;
  public Class1(IDataClassesDataContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  public List<BookList> GetBookList(int bookid)
  {

    List<BookList> _BookList = new List<BookList>();
   //Consider if some wcf call is there then how we can develop unit test
    using (_context)
    {
      foreach (tblBook_Sel_BasedOnbookIDResult _tblBook_selResult in _context.tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID(bookid))
        {
            BookList _bookListObject = new BookList();
            //Setting the proerty here
            _BookList.Add(_bookListObject);
        }

    }
    return _BookList;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please suggest me how basically should write this method so i can write a effective unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible scenarios:

1. bookId parameter is negative, zero and positive. You can use `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue`.
2. `_strConnectionStringName` is null, empty, invalid and valid.
3. Tests for possible exceptions that can be thrown by `tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID` method.
4. Based on properties of the `BookList` class, you can have multiple test cases.

Please note that you should be calling a mock `tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID` method here. This method does not really care what goes on inside `tblBook_Sel_BasedOnBookID`. However, it looks a tad difficult are you are dealing with concrete type here.

For service, again a mock service call should made instead to making a real service call and based on conditions it can return a hard coded result or an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This function is a stretched out two-liner, where one of the lines is **data access**. This function would be one I'd mock to unit test those that rely on it. You cannot unit test it, because it relies on outside data sources and therefore is not a single unit. If external sources are involved, you can use [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) instead.

Comment: For unit testing the function should be one liner?and if function required some database call then it should be in different method and need to use the only out put from other but still there dependency so how i can it separate out please suggest.

Comment: @Gautam No, the function can have as many lines as you want for unit testing. But it needs to be a **unit**. Your function not only has external dependencies (which could be mocked and injected) but actually **only consists of this dependency**. If you take out the dependency to make it a unit again, there is nothing left but a pair of empty braces.